# check if string matches first n characters of regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a python site built in Django where a user will be uploading files that they may or may not have permission to add. The permissions are created through a series of regex patterns (there is over 1000). At one point in my site I have a place for the user to view their permissions (using a search filter and a list). However what I want to do is if the user types in a string and the string matches any part of each regular expression. I want it in the list.

Right now I have `if(filter.match(pattern)) { //add pattern to list }`
I have also tried searching instead of matching.

An example of what I am looking for:

If I have a list of regex patterns:

```
^(12345678)\.(txt)$
^(qwertyuiop)\.(txt)$
^(qwerty)\.(txt)$
^(23456)\.(txt)$
```

if the user were to enter qwert the list would show `^(qwertyuiop)\.(txt)$` and `^(qwerty)\.(txt)$`, whereas if the user entered qwertyu the list would only show `^(qwertyuiop)\.(txt)$`. Similarly if the user entered 234 the list would show `^(12345678)\.(txt)$` and `^(23456)\.(txt)$` but if the user entered 1 the list would only show `^(12345678)\.(txt)$`.

Is it possible to accomplish this?
If so how would I manage it?

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: `in` will do the job,  `[pattern for pattern in patterns_list if input_string in pattern]`

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` should work for this. By the sound of it you're not too picky with users entering arbitrary strings that could crash your server. If so you could just do this.

```py
import re

patterns = [
    r"^(12345678)\.(txt)$",
    r"^(qwertyuiop)\.(txt)$",
    r"^(qwerty)\.(txt)$",
    r"^(23456)\.(txt)$",
]

filter = re.compile("qwert")
filtered_patterns = [p for p in patterns if filter.search(p)]
```